# Pass Node Name as testing Condition in Chef Recipe

Tags: automation, chef-infra, conditional-statements, chef-recipe

I am writing a simple recipe to install any package. The only change I am trying to achieve is that my recipe should only install the package if the node name matches else it should do nothing. My code is

```
package "vim" do
  if node["name"] == "MyNode"
    action :install
  else
    action :nothing
  end
end
```

In this case, package does not install even on the node with name MyNode. I also tried using `only_if` as follows:

```
package "vim" do
  only_if node["name"] == "MyNode"
    action :install
end
```

In this case, it installs the package on every node irrespective of its name! I am either messing up the syntax on missing something.

Can someone tell me What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
package "vim" if node["name"] == "MyNode"
```

But your first example should work, I guess. May be *node["name"]* on your node is different from *"MyNode"*?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do this when deploying different datadog jmx configs for different services. (since datadog has a limited number of metrics it can collect)
I did it with a case statement in the recipe.

```
case Chef::Config[:node_name]
  when 'host1.domain.name'
  cookbook_file '/etc/dd-agent/conf.d/jmx.yaml' do
    source 'default/host1/jmx.yaml'
    owner 'dd-agent'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    action :create
  end
  when 'host2.domain.name'
  cookbook_file '/etc/dd-agent/conf.d/jmx.yaml' do
    source 'default/host2/jmx.yaml'
    ...
  end
end
```